# dotfuscator getting error Non-public instance method in interface

Tags: c#, dotfuscator, ilasm

I'm using dotfuscator 6.3 community. dotfuscator builds fails with the message `ilasm returned 1`.

dotfuscator builds fails after following exectution
`Running C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ilasm.exe -OUTPUT=C:\Users\██████\AppData\Local\Temp\Dotfuscator_16676\~██████.13\stub-pdb\██████.██████.dll -nologo  -quiet -dll  -PDB -MDV=v4.0.30319 -MSV=2.0 C:\Users\██████\AppData\Local\Temp\Dotfuscator_16676\~██████.13\██████.██████.dll.il -resource=C:\Users\██████\AppData\Local\Temp\Dotfuscator_16676\~Alterun.13\██████.██████.dll.res`

Running ILAsm from the terminal I get `Non-public instance method in interface` from ILAsm.

I installed ILAsm v4.700.2 and set dotfuscator to use that, but dotfuscator reports that ILAsm returned `-1073740791`.
Running it from the terminal doesn't report any errors but I don't get any output file.

I tried using the 4.700.2 ildasm but got errors too. In the terminal, I get `INVALID COMMAND LINE OPTION: -TEXT`, removing `-TEXT`, it reports `# GitHub/3F Edition specially for .NET DllExport: https://github.com/3F v4.700.2.0+4fde65a56` and the files are generated. But ilasm still doesn't output the dll.

One thing to note is that `-MDV=v4.0.30319 -MSV=2.0` causes ilasm report `Could not open .0.30319 Could not open .0`, adding brackets or removing those options resolves any errors.